# Executing dynamically generated code on RISC-V

Tags: memory-management, paging, riscv, forth, riscv32

I am writing a Forth-like language for RISC-V and naturally that means I need to have a way to allow the users to define new words and execute them.

But I am struggling to find a way that will allow users to execute dynamically generated code without using privileged instructions to change a page's status. Is there any way to do this - for example, can I define a large empty section in .text (as opposed to .bss which is what I am currently doing)?

Or do I have to write an explicit trap handler?

Update: I am using the pk proxy kernel with Spike. I am executing an mprotect system call against either a buffer created in the .bss section or an allocation in the .text section.

In either case the mprotect call fails - returning -EACCES. (So using the .bss version fails on any attempt to execute the new code and using the .text version fails when I attempt to write the new code.)

It seems I cannot mark a page as R/W/X - and this might be fundamental. Is there a way round this (there surely must be!)

Comment: What simulator / execution environment are you using?

Comment: Spike with pk proxy kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem was to use mmap to map in a range of addresses with the appropriate READ, WRITE and EXECUTE permissions.

```
mv a0, zero
li a1, BIGSPACE
li a2, 0x07
li a3, 0x22
li a4, -1
li a5, 0x0
li a7, 222
ecall
```